# Implementing YouTube Data API (Search: List) Android Studio

Tags: java, android, gradle

this is my first post on stack overflow so I apologize if I am not formatting correctly.

I've been trying to add YouTube's data api to my project in android studio.  There are not really any good youtube tutorials to do so.  So far, I have followed this guide here: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/youtube/v3.  However, following these steps for my project gradle, not everything is imported.  The IDE does not recognize:

```
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;

import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
```

This causes the code not to run at all.  I have other issues as well, but it seems as if this is the first problem that I need to tackle.  I'm in high school, so I can't really ask a coworker or anything and felt that this was a good place to turn.

Comment: hi, have you added API gradle dependencies to build.gradle ? ie              repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev192-1.23.0'
}

Comment: I had already done this.  In android studio's project gradle file I added the maven central line and in the module:app file I added the dependencies "compile" line.  All of the imports then work properly except for the two that I listed in the original post.

Comment: This is going to sound ridiculous, but it somehow fixed itself.  I no longer have any error messages!  Onto the next step now...